# Can you Calculate Magnetism at a Material's Surface?

Tags: density-functional-theory, surfaces, nanostructures, nanoparticles

I'm researching FePt L10 nanoparticles and want to know how their surfaces affect their magnetic properties. However, I can't seem to find any papers on this topic.

Specifically, I would like to know what the magnetic behaviour at {111} surfaces in FePt L10 is like, and how this might affect the behaviour of the particle in general.

Questions of interest would be: "Does the {111} surface have significantly lower anisotropy than the {100} and {001} surfaces?", and "How does a nanoparticle's surface affect its coercivity?".

Is it practically possible to investigate this using DFT or an experiment?

Comment: What magnetic properties are you interested in? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Greg Is what I'm interested in clearer now?

Comment: It looks more clear for me (yet, I do not know the answer :) ).

Comment: Since it's been more than 6 months now, I wonder if you have any update on this? Did you figure out the answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani Unfortunately, no, I didn't find out the answer!

Comment: Okay! I see 4 question marks in this question, are you able to reduce it to one question?

Comment: Two of the question marks are used to indicate the kind of question I would like to answer if it's possible to model magnetism at a material's surface. I can put the latter two into a single one though.

Comment: Does the sentence starting with "Questions of interest would be: "? I know you'd probably prefer to have it there, but I'm trying to help this question get answered, based on experience :)

Comment: I'll remove the two other questions!

Comment: How is this going now? Did you find an answer? Are you actively still in need of an answer?

Comment: No answer, would still love one! But I don't need one anymore.